# My SQL Query: Error :Unknown column in field list when using CASE WHEN in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

Hi everyone,i am a beginner of mysql query. I have one error when using this query in mysql:

```
SELECT enquiry.business_id ,enquiry_count ,b.`business_name`,c.`id`
FROM `consumer_guide_enquiry_company` enquiry
INNER JOIN `businesses` b ON  `enquiry`.`business_id`=b.`business_id`
INNER JOIN `consumer_guide_company` c ON c.`business_id`=b.`business_id` 
WHERE CASE 
WHEN enquiry.`business_id` 
IN (
SELECT b.business_id 
FROM `businesses` b,`consumer_guide_company` c 
WHERE b.`business_id`=c.`business_id` AND c.`consumer_guide_id`=1) 
THEN enquiry_count=COUNT(enquiry.enquiry_id) 
ELSE enquiry_count=0 
END
GROUP BY enquiry.business_id
```

**It display error: Unknown column 'enquiry_count' in 'field list'**

Thanks for your helping

Comment: do you have the column in  any of your tables ?

Comment: `enquiry_count` to `enquiry.enquiry_count`

Comment: No , i don't have any enquiry_count column in any table. I don't know how to select a value is calculated in CASE WHEN THEN ElSE END expression, so i define enquiry_count value in CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END

Comment: Why you are using SET in Where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
SELECT enquiry.business_id ,case when enquiry_count is NULL then  0 
else enquiry_count end 'enquiry_count'  ,b.`business_name`,c.`id`
FROM `consumer_guide_enquiry_company` enquiry

INNER JOIN `businesses` b ON  `enquiry`.`business_id`=b.`business_id`
INNER JOIN `consumer_guide_company` c ON c.`business_id`=b.`business_id` 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.business_id,count(*) as enquiry_count FROM `businesses`
b,`consumer_guide_company` c WHERE b.`business_id`=c.`business_id` AND  
c.`consumer_guide_id`=1 group by b.business_id) as tt 
ON enquiry.`business_id`=tt.b.business_id
GROUP BY enquiry.business_id
```

Comment: I tried your query, but it display : "case when enquiry_count is NULL then  0  else enquiry_count end" as one column name of result.

Comment: use the same but after end add as enquiry_count

Comment: that is `case when enquiry_count is NULL then 0 else enquiry_count end as equiry_count`

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: It display error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as enquiry_count'

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille i get above syntax in following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result

Comment: @SATSON yes just saw it :).. hopefully  it works for beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

you should not mention the name `where is tablename.enquiry_count`

**your code error in this following line:**

**wrong code line:1**

```
SELECT enquiry.business_id ,enquiry_count ,b.`business_name`,c.`id`
```

---

**wrong code line:2**

```
    THEN enquiry_count=COUNT(enquiry.enquiry_id) 
    ELSE enquiry_count=0
```

**you should mention the:** tablename

```
   tablename.enquiry_count
```

Comment: I think the OP `enquiry_count` value set in where clause . In OP Query `CASE WHEN enquiry.`business_id` IN (SELECT b.business_id FROM `businesses` b,`consumer_guide_company` c WHERE b.`business_id`=c.`business_id` AND c.`consumer_guide_id`=1) THEN enquiry_count=COUNT(enquiry.enquiry_id) 
ELSE enquiry_count=0 ` So the field not in table

Comment: @SATSON : yes , you are right. The field is not in any table .

Comment: @jmail how will the beginner mention tablename.enquiry_count when there is no such column in the table ???