# MySQL - How to Join these tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

company

```
id | name    | domain
1  | sample1 | one.sample.lan
2  | sample2 | two.sample.lan
```

permissions

```
id | moduleid | permid
5  | 12       | 2
```

If permissions for a module are set to a company in permissions-table there will be set the id of the module (here 12) and the id of the company (here 2) the normal id of permissions is auto incremented. If the permissions will be removed the full row will be deleted from permissions.

I want to get the following from my select:

```
company.name | company.domain | selected
```

I want to get all companys, doesnt matter if they are set or not set. With the Information if they are selected (in the table permissions) as 1 or 0.

Something like:

```
SELECT company.name, company.domain 
FROM company LEFT JOIN permissions ON (company.id = permissions.permid) 
WHERE permissions.moduleid = 12;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but i didnt understand, are you telling me you want a select case?  `CASE permissions.moduleId
   when is null  then 0 else 1`... Something like this?

Comment: @DiogodeGóesZanetti This is the way I interpreted the question as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use distinct to get each company only once, and use if or case structure to decide if it exist in the permissions table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company.name, company.domain, if(permissions.permid is null, 0, 1) as selected
FROM company LEFT JOIN permissions ON (company.id = permissions.permid) 
WHERE permissions.moduleid = 12;
```

UPDATE: If you want to check which companies have access to a specific module, then move the where criteria into the join condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company.name, company.domain, if(permissions.permid is null, 0, 1) as selected
FROM company LEFT JOIN permissions ON (company.id = permissions.permid) and permissions.moduleid = 12;
```

Comment: The if-clause works properly, but now i only get the permission where moduleid = 12. Because of that i only get comany named sample2. I want to get sample1 too with a 0 in the if statement... Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Adding more information to this question. Please look at this topic with informations on select case examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result

Comment: @JoshuaH. then remove the where criteria from the statement.

Comment: @Diogo de Góes Zanetti The problem is in the where-clause. Can i do a case in where clause too? something like ...WHERE IF(moduleid exists, permissions.moduleid = 12, permissions.moduleid is null)

Comment: @Shadow If i remove the where statement i will get a 1 in if-clause for all modules, not for the one i want to see...

Comment: @JoshuaH.Do you want to check if a company has access to module 12? If yes, then move the where criteria into the join condition.

Comment: @Shadow How can i move the where criteria into the join condition?

Comment: @JoshuaH. Copy-paste will do :) On a more serious note, see the updated answer.