# Implementing a case statement based on the values in another column - MySQL

Tags: mysql

hi guys I'm trying to do a stored procedure with a loan period where if the Book Column is filled it will add 14 days and if the video column is filled it will only add 7 days in my 'Due Date' column.

I have it working where it records my member ID and transaction date with the NOW() statement and pulls from my item table if its a book or movie with the item number I'm just unsure how I would go about doing the due date. I've played around and made a case statement with how I want it to work but unsure how I go about implementing it into my stored procedure code.

**Stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Loan Renew`(
in Member_ID INT(11), 
in `ITEM ID` INT(11))
INSERT INTO loan_table (Member_ID,item_id,book_id,Video_id,Transaction_date,Due_Date)
select Member_ID,Item_ID,Book_ID,video_id,NOW()
FROM item_table
Where `ITEM ID` =Item_table.Item_id
```

**CASE STATEMENT:**

```
CASE book_ID 
WHEN Book_ID IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_ADD(transaction_date,INTERVAL 14 DAY)
ELSE  DATE_ADD(transaction_date,INTERVAL 56 DAY)
END AS 'Due_date'
from loan_table
Where `ITEM ID` =Item_table.Item_id
```

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result/8600850#8600850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Loan Renew`(
in Member_ID INT(11), 
in `ITEM ID` INT(11))
INSERT INTO loan_table (Member_ID,item_id,book_id,Video_id,Transaction_date,Due_Date)
select Member_ID,Item_ID,Book_ID,video_id,NOW(),
        CASE -- book_ID 
        WHEN Book_ID IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)
        ELSE  DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 56 DAY)
        END
FROM item_table
Where `ITEM ID` =Item_table.Item_id
```

Comment: i seem to be getting an unknown column 'transaction_date' field list' now

Comment: sorry, edited, with now() that applies to 'transaction_date'