# MySQL: change Boolean column to Decimal column, and Cast() existing data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In MySQL, I need to convert an existing Boolean field to a Decimal field. Also, I need to cast Null to Null, t to 0.10, and f to 0.00. How should I do something like this inside MySQL?

```
my_db => select distinct my_field from my_table;
 my_field
-------------

 t
 f
(3 rows)
```

Comment: You need to use SQL case , see below example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result

Comment: You need to use SQL case , see below example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

If you don't have any constraints on this column, try to add columns them drop after:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_new_column DECIMAL after my_field;

UPDATE my_table
    SET my_decimal_field = (
        CASE WHEN my_field = true THEN 0.1 
            ELSE 
                CASE WHEN my_field = false THEN 0.0 
                ELSE Null
            END
        END);

ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN my_field;
```

Comment: Will this convert the Boolean column to Decimal column also?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the `NULL` rows, because `NULL` is `NULL`, whether the column is Boolean or decimal.

You also don't need to worry about rows where the value is `false`, because `false` automatically casts to `0`

So all you need to concern yourself with are the rows that were `true`, which will cast to `1`.  So, alter your table structure first, and then change all the `1`s to `0.10`s:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE my_field my_field DECIMAL(10,2) ;

UPDATE my_table SET my_field = 0.10 WHERE my_field = 1 ;
```