# MySQL Where OR Query result an Alias

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is it possible to get a result which OR-Query

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE age = 18 OR age = 0
```

Result:

```
| name |
----------
| Tim |
| Tom |
| Olli |
```

But I need:

Result:

```
| name | alias |
------------
| Tim | no-age |
| Tom | age18 |
| Olli | age18 |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use a `case` expression in the select list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select statement with CASE or IF ELSEIF? Not sure how to get the result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression to translate the age to the result you want.
Note also that the condition in the `where` clause could be rewritten with the `in` operator to make it more elegant:

```
SELECT name, CASE age WHEN 0 THEN 'no-age' ELSE 'age18' END AS `alias`
FROM   mytable
WHERE  age IN (18, 0)
```

Comment: In case of Two {SELECT Querys for example SELECT count(`id`) AS sum FROM `tabel` WHERE `cloumn1` = 0"} and  {SELECT Querys for example SELECT count(`id`) AS sum FROM `tabel` WHERE `cloumn2` = 0"} Is it possible to get one Sum?

Comment: yes possible. search for such queries on SO or post new question