# search one value in two columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, joomla

I have a problem with my MySQL code in php. I made my own search plugin for Joomla site.
This plugin search ONE value from search input. You can enter a company registration number or company name in the search box. The extension should look in two columns that are in one table.

SQL table "registered_companies"

```
id | regnumber | name | col4 | col5 | col6 etc
01 | 17333032 | company1 | bla | bla | bla
02 | 36302465 | company2 | bla | bla | bla
03 | 17311161 | company3 | bla | bla | bla
04 | 651664   | company4 | bla | bla | bla
05 | 17318599 | company5 | bla | bla | bla
```

in my php code I have SQL select

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT *
            FROM registered_companies 
            WHERE ".$searchInput." IN(regnumber, name)";
```

With this code (i tried several variations) it works only if I try to find number (regnumber). If I enter a text string like "company1", SQL returns error 1054 Unknown column 'company1' in 'where clause'.

I try use `WHERE regnumber LIKE ".$searchInput;`
That's fine, but of course the command searches only one column, and all my multiple LIKE and OR commands ended up being a error.

What am I doing wrong? How do I type an SQL command to do what I want?

thx for help

Comment: `WHERE regnumber LIKE 'stringTOSearch' OR name LIKE 'stringTOSearch'`

Comment: this works, thx. I add this [code]WHERE regnumber LIKE 'stringTOSearch' OR name LIKE '%stringTOSearch%'[/code]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add % to your searching string..

```
$searchInput = "%".$searchInput."%";
```

Then prepare, bind, execute and fetch

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM registered_companies WHERE regnumber LIKE :searchInput OR name LIKE :searchInput";
$dbResult = $db->prepare($sql);
$dbResult->bindValue(':searchInput', $searchInput, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$dbResult->execute();

while($line = $dbResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
   //... do what you need ... 
   // $name = $line['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should turn your SELECT statement to:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT *
            FROM registered_companies 
            WHERE regnumber = ".$searchInput." OR name LIKE '".$searchInput."%'";
```

This seems to work, but beware of SQL-Injection. You should work with prepared statements instead. Have a look at the PHP-Docs for the prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Depending on your comaparision for the columns `regnumber` and `name` you have to change the `=` and `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle two different cases (if $searchInput is TEXT or INT).

I suggest you read about 'CASE':

[MySQL select statement with CASE or IF ELSEIF? Not sure how to get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result)