# Writing a subquery with a case statement

Tags: php, mysql

From this query

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN STATUS = ONE THEN STATUS 
WHEN STATUS = TWO THEN STATUS 
WHEN ONE = TWO THEN ONE 
ELSE NULL END answer FROM TABLE1
```

how do i get rows based on the "answer",suppose i want a where condition like,
`...where answer='yes'`, how do i write that sub query

EDIT1:

Sample Table output from the above mentioned query:

```
|STATUS |ONE    |TWO    |answer
|NO     |NO     |YES    |NO
|YES    |YES    |NO     |YES
|NO     |NO     |NO     |NO
```

Expected Output with where condition on "answer" (Example, where answer='yes')

```
|STATUS |ONE    |TWO    |answer
|YES    |YES    |NO     |YES
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result

Comment: Please post your table structure and simple data with expected output.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod. updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post table structure, but based on your sample output I assumed there are 3 columns named `status`,`one` and `two` as demonstrated in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c82c3/1/0)

If that's the case. Following query may work for you.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN status = one THEN status
WHEN status = two THEN status
WHEN one = two THEN one 
ELSE NULL END answer 
FROM `TABLE1` 
HAVING answer='YES';
```