# Merge two columns in MySQL and ignore the NULL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

MySQL data table are as follows:

```
Column1   Column2
A         NULL
B         NULL
NULL      C
NULL      D
NULL      NULL
```

Need output as follows:

```
Column3
A
B
C
D
NULL
```

How can i get this merging? 
**MySQL query would be preferable.** 
If no options available in the end then i can look for python code.

Comment: See COALESCE().

Comment: @Strawberry It is really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select COALESCE(Column1, Column2) as Column3 from tablename
```

This is working.

Comment: Perfect Solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need to join tables on common columns and use case in mysql.
You can do something as below..

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT CASE
    WHEN orig_tbl1.col1 IS NOT NULL THEN orig_tbl1.col1
    WHEN orig_tbl1.col2 IS NOT NULL THEN orig_tbl1.col2
    ELSE NULL
    END , orig_tbl1.col2,orig_tbl1.col3,
 FROM orig_tbl1,orig_tbl2 where orig_tbl1.id = orig_tbl2.id ;
```

You can try this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8600850/1069633