# MySQL - IF/THEN Statement Query

Tags: mysql

Greetings from the Seychelles Islands, Everyone :-)

I am working on a MySQL database project and have ran into a brick wall and wondering if anyone can help me out.

Basically I have a table in the database that stores the value of an aircraft's MTOW value in its field: MTOW. I also have another field, Landing Fee, which is intended to calculate the aircraft's landing fee based on its MTOW value inputted previously.

There are several conditions for this Landing Fee:

If the MTOW is less than 10000 Kgs, the Landing Fee should be (MTOW x 22.00)
If the MTOW is between 10000 Kgs and less than 60000 Kgs, the Landing Fee should be (MTOW x 27.00) and so on.

Now my question is how do I select the aircraft's record and have its Landing Fee calculated automatically based on the MTOW value?

Is this possible?

Please advise.

Thank You & Kind Regards,

Idris Jamil Afif (Mr.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning Idris.

I think you should look up [**MySQL `CASE` queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result) and then run the CASE for each value of `MTOW` that needs to be checked, and
run the appropriate calculation when the correct value is found.

For example:

```
SELECT columns, more_columns, CASE 
    WHEN `MTOW` < 10000 THEN (`MTOW` * 22) 
    WHEN (`MTOW` > 9999 AND `MTOW` < 60000) THEN (`MTOW` * 27)
    ... 
    ELSE 'some default value' 
    END as landing_fee,
    further_columns
FROM table 
WHERE....
```

Comment: Dear Martin, 

Thank You for this - I will try it out and revert back on the outcome.

Would you be so kind to share your contact details with me?

Comment: @IdrisJamilAfif it is best if you simply use comments on this Stack Overflow thread `:-)`

Comment: No Worries :-)
The solution above worked - Thank You once again

Answer (score 0):

A view will do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE aircrafts (
  MTOW DOUBLE
);

CREATE VIEW aircrafts_with_fee as
  SELECT MTOW,
  IF (MTOW < 10000, MTOW*22,
      IF (MTOW < 60000, MTOW*27, 0)
  ) as LANDING_FEE
  FROM aircrafts;
```

Comment: Nested IF conditionals are unpleasent to work with and easily prone to coder typos. Also MySQL the variable names should be lower case, you seem to have inverted the case in your example.

Comment: Much appreciated for this, user3253654 :-)