# if elseif conditions in mysql query

Tags: mysql

due to lack of SUPER privileges in hosting, I need to convert some stored procedures to SQL queries.
I tried:

```
SET @condition = 0;

IF (@condition = 0) THEN
   SELECT 'IF result' AS res;
ELSEIF (@condition = 1) THEN
   SELECT 'ELSEIF result' AS res;   
ELSE
   SELECT 'ELSE result' AS res;
END IF;
```

But I got sintax error:

*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSEIF (@condition = 1) THEN
SELECT 'ELSEIF result' AS res' at line 1*

Comment: `IF` flow control statement can only be used in stored routine. Use `SELECT CASE....` instead

Comment: You can use `case` as this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600671/mysql-select-statement-with-case-or-if-elseif-not-sure-how-to-get-the-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below:

```
 SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN @condition=1 THEN 'if result'
            WHEN @condition=0 THEN 'elseif result'
            ELSE 'else result'
            END AS res;
```

Comment: That's working  but now I have a new problem: If I try `WHEN @condition=0 THEN (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 1)` I got error `ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)` But I need more columns or all on each condition. You have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @MTK you need to specify only one column but you are using `*` to return all the columns now

Comment: I have posted another question here about this case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68264848/2951051

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CASE ELSE END](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)
Maybe the SQL confuses with the IF statement being a string in the quotation mark

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```