# alternative to CASE WHEN to return all columns not only one

Tags: mysql

Due to lack of SUPER privileges in hosting, I need to convert some stored procedures to SQL queries.

Initially I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68264382/2951051) about how to use conditions in queries, which already has an answer, is correct and is useful when I need only one column.
But now my problem is that I need sometimes to return multiple or all columns and then CASE WHEN does not work for me

So I need some like this:

```
SET @condition = 0;

IF (@condition = 0) THEN
   SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 1;
ELSEIF (@condition = 1) THEN
   SELECT 'ELSEIF result' AS res; 
ELSE
   SELECT 'ELSE result' AS res;
END IF;
```

But this got syntax error:

If I use CASE

```
SET @condition = 0;
SELECT  CASE 
WHEN @condition=0 THEN (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 1)
WHEN @condition=1 THEN 'elseif result'
ELSE 'else result'
END AS res;
```

That working good for `@condition = 1` OR `ELSE` case, but if `@condition = 0` I got error : `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

*Any suggestions to simulate conditions in a query of this type will be welcome.*

Comment: The structure of your two (three?) possible expected result sets differ.  One is `SELECT *`, presumably many columns, while the other is a string.  You would probably have to handle this from a stored proc, or from your application layer.

Comment: Yes. I have given intentional so because sometimes I need only one column and sometimes several. I have started my question by saying `Due to lack of SUPER privileges in hosting, I need to convert some stored procedures to SQL queries` So I cannot handle this from procedures

Comment: You can't do this from a (non dynamic) SQL query AFAIK.

Comment: Ok. Thank's. Due to your reputation ... I think you are right ... So I need to rethink my design for the queries

Comment: Rep doesn't mean much, and I'm often wrong about things on this site.  If you always expected the same number and type of columns, I could give you a union trick which would work.  But not for differing number/types of columns.

Comment: No. They are not always the same. Before I had it in stored procedures and functions but after 5 years of work, a few days ago, "Someone very clever" from the hosting has taken away the right to create functions, procedures. And my site is down !!! Sorry for my English